# How to remove the comma before the last author on titlepage?

Tags: titles, authblk

I use the `authblk` package to write author and their affliations. In my case, there are 3 authors with common affiliation.  But it shows output like this: "firstauthor, secondauthor, and thirdauthor".

By default it gives comma before "and". Should it not be only "and"?. Is it accepatable to write comma before "and". Or it is correct?. What it should be?

Here is my title.tex fle.

```
  \title{Individual Spread Footing}
  \author{Manpreet Kaur}
  \author{Monisha}
  \author{Amritpal Singh}
  \affil{Guru Nanak Dev Engineering College, Ludhiana}  
 \begin{titlepage}
   \maketitle
   % ADDING TABLE Of CONTENT
   \tableofcontents
   \listoffigures
   \listofcharts
   \listoftables
 \end{titlepage}
```

output:

[image]

Comment: This is called the "Oxford comma" or "serial comma" and there is a lively debate about whether to use it, but it is certainly not out and out wrong, just a matter of style. Some publications will demand it. Some will prohibit it. Some will not care. It is, however, an English language usage question, not really a LaTeX question, unless you're asking how to insert or remove it?

Comment: Whether you should use the Oxford comma depends on the sentence (you need to see which version changes the meaning of the sentence), see also [Oxford Comma Conventions](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/172671/6550), but like Au101 said, this is a question related to usage in the English language and is unrelated to TeX.

Comment: Oddly, this seems more common in the US. (Although I guess OUP use it in the UK, too.) Many people will tell you it is simply wrong. I'm not aware of anybody who says omitting it is wrong, but surely there are some.

Comment: If the answer is helpful consider accepting it, which would mark your question as solved.

Answer (score 6):

Whether the comma is used or not is a question of style. Both choices are acceptable.

If you want to remove the comma, known as “Oxford comma”, just redefine `\Authands`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authblk}

\renewcommand{\Authands}{ and } % comment the line to have the Oxford comma

\begin{document}

\title{Individual Spread Footing}
\author{Manpreet Kaur}
\author{Monisha}
\author{Amritpal Singh}
\affil{Guru Nanak Dev Engineering College, Ludhiana}

\begin{titlepage}
  \maketitle
  % ADDING TABLE Of CONTENT
  \tableofcontents
  \listoffigures
  \listofcharts
  \listoftables
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]